CDF matching approach
Good evening,
I need to apply the CDF matching approach to normalized (transforms a time series' mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis to approximately harmonize the reference time series) the remotely sensed data before applying statistical indices to check the reliability and performance of satellite soil moisture estimations against ground-based measurements. I don't know how to apply the CDF matching approach to temporal data sets.
Thank you so much for any help
The following is what I did:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy
import math


# Lettura dei dati
data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx',sheet_name='l4')

data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'])
data.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)

def NormalizeData(value):
    min_val=np.min(value)
    max_val=np.max(value)
    return (value - min_val)/(max_val - min_val)

P=data.P
Pn=NormalizeData(data.P)
SSM=data.SSM
SSMn=NormalizeData(data.SSM)
    
data= data.dropna()

Ref_data = NormalizeData(data.P)
Biased_data = NormalizeData(data.SSM)


# Funzione per calcolare la distribuzione cumulativa (CDF)

def prob_data(data):
    data = data[~np.isnan(data)]
    #sorted_data = np.sort(data)
    n = len(data)
    ret = np.arange(1, n + 1) / (n + 1)
    return ret

# CDF Matching
Prob_ref = prob_data(Ref_data)
Prof_biased = prob_data(Biased_data)

# Calcolo del bias prima della correzione
bias = np.sum(Biased_data - Ref_data) / len(Biased_data)


#Interpolazione lineare 1-D
interp_func = interp1d(np.sort(Prof_biased), np.sort(Biased_data), fill_value="extrapolate")
Biased_interpolated = interp_func(np.sort(Prob_ref))

# Fit polinomiale
n = 5  # Grado del polinomio
p = np.polyfit(Biased_interpolated, np.sort(Ref_data) - Biased_interpolated, n)


# Correzione dei dati
Corrected_Data = np.polyval(p, Biased_data) + Biased_data

# Calcolo del bias dopo la correzione
bias_after = np.sum(Corrected_Data - Ref_data) / len(Corrected_Data)

# Plotting
plt.plot(np.sort(Ref_data), Prob_ref, 'k-', linewidth=1.5, label='Reference data')
plt.plot(np.sort(Biased_data), Prof_biased, 'k--', linewidth=1.5, label='Biased data')
plt.plot(np.sort(Corrected_Data), prob_data(Corrected_Data), 'k:', linewidth=1.5, label='Corrected data')


plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.gcf().set_facecolor('white')
plt.savefig('CDF SSM PLOT.png', format='png',dpi=100)
plt.show()

data_correct=Corrected_Data.to_frame()
data_correct.reset_index(inplace=True)

date = data_correct['Timestamp']
data_correct['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(date)

data_correct = (data_correct.set_index('Timestamp').reindex(pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2021-12-31',freq='D')).rename_axis(['Date']).fillna('').reset_index())

data_correct.rename(columns={'SSM': 'SSM cdf'}, inplace=True)
data_correct['P'] = P.values
data_correct['Pn'] = Pn.values
data_correct['SSM'] = SSM.values
data_correct['SSMn'] =SSMn.values

data_correct.to_excel('L4_data.xlsx')


Can you clarify what you mean by 'CDF matching?'

CDF-matching transforms a time series' mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis to ap-proximately harmonize the reference time series
